# Which version of mapbasic to use for maximum interoperability with different mapinfo versions?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

The oldest mapbasic download offered by pbinsight these days seems to be version 9.5.  I wonder can all subsequent versions of mapinfo run compiled code written with this?

If so, is an older (and hence more compatible) version of mapbasic available anywhere?

If not, which version is the best bet for a new application, without wanting to shut out potential users who don't have the latest version of mapinfo?

Comment: not officially - have it on disc (v8), but prevented from copying/distributing it due to licensing.

Comment: so does that mean older versions _are_ compatible with the latest mapinfo?

Comment: @SideshowBob No it does not! I have found mapbasic application not run in various versions! Although if it would run icons may disappear! mapbasic version 10.5 can use same ID for icons where if I use this code in 10 all icons would be same. So it would be the best to use same mapinfo version through out the organization eliminating any chance of complain or else test through all version of mapinfo that might be used since multiple version of mapinfo can be installed in the same device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiled MapBasic should run with any version of MapInfo Pro equal or higher.
Strictly speaking it depends on what features you use in the MapBasic.
The compiled code is compatible but a version number is compiled in and this is checked against the MapInfo Pro version.

There is a utility floating around which scans the compiled MapBasic and resets the version number to the lowest which supports the features used. I will dig out the URL for that when I get home if you're interested.